# CMake ExternalProject_Add on Visual Studio receiving error MSB1009 (but library builds)

Tags: cmake

I am attempting to add [glad](https://github.com/Dav1dde/glad) to a build using ExternalProject_Add. Everything is downloading correctly and seems to be building as expected as the library is built and placed into the correct directory...However...

For some reason I'm receiving the following error message during build time using visual studio:

```
3>MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
3>Switch: install.vcxproj
3>Done building project "glad.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
```

It would seem that this is happening because glad does not generate an `INSTALL.vcxproj` file (cmake only generating ALL_BUILD and ZERO_CHECK projects but not INSTALL).

Therefore, how might one go about circumventing this situation? Below is relevant cmake section:

```
set(libGLAD glad)
ExternalProject_Add(${libGLAD}
PREFIX          ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/dep/${libGLAD}
GIT_REPOSITORY  https://github.com/Dav1dde/glad.git
GIT_TAG         origin/master
GIT_SHALLOW     ON
CMAKE_ARGS      -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/dep/${libGLAD}
                -DGLAD_PROFILE:STRING="core"
                -DGLAD_ALL_EXTENSIONS:BOOL=ON
                -DUSE_MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY_DLL:BOOL=OFF
)
```

Comment: GLad project generates the install command only when variable `GLAD_INSTALL`  is set: https://github.com/Dav1dde/glad/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L53. So you need either set this variable in your `ExternalProject_Add` or tell CMake to not generate `install` target with `INSTALL_COMMAND ""`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Ah! That just made several other aspects of cmake click for me as well. If you would like to turn this into an answer I would "glad"-ly accept :)